# Change the default database in Oracle Pro*C

Tags: c, oracle

I have two Oracle databases on the same dev server.

When I do `SELECT ORA_DATABASE_NAME FROM DUAL;` I get

DATABASE1.SERVER as the name for the first one and DATABASE2.SERVER as the name for the second.

When I use `EXEC SQL CONNECT :userid IDENTIFIED BY :pwd;` in my Pro*C program, it is automatically defaulting to DATABASE1.

I am able to explicitly connect to DATABASE2 by using `EXEC SQL CONNECT :userid IDENTIFIED BY :pwd AT DB_NAME USING :dbname;` ,however if I connect this way, I would need to change every single place where I use `EXEC SQL` to `EXEC SQL AT DB_NAME` throughout all the code.  This is not feasible since there are hundreds of Pro*C legacy files that would have to be changed.

My current test code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <pwd.h>

EXEC SQL INCLUDE sqlca;

void main()
{

EXEC SQL DECLARE DB_NAME DATABASE;

   char *userid = "user1";
   char *pwd = "password1";
   char *dbname = "DATABASE2";
   int c;

/*   EXEC SQL CONNECT :userid IDENTIFIED BY :pwd AT DB_NAME USING :dbname;*/  // When I execute      this line, I connect to DATABASE2 as desired
     EXEC SQL CONNECT :userid IDENTIFIED BY :pwd; //when I execute this line, I connect to the       default database, DATABASE1, which is not desired

   printf("Database returned: %i\n",sqlca.sqlcode);

 //This SQL is what I have to use when connecting to DATABASE2 explicitly
 /*  EXEC SQL AT DB_NAME select count(*)
     into c
     from table1;
 */

 //This SQL is the code I need to use, by connecting to DATABASE2 as the default database
   EXEC SQL select count(*)
   into c
   from table1;

   printf("count: %i\n",c);

}
```

I have scoured Oracle's documentation trying to find out how to change what the default database connection is, but all I've found is [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_03dbc.htm), which only states THAT there is a default connection, not how to change it.

Comment: I'm not a Pro*C expert but I would expect that the default would be driven by the `ORACLE_SID` environment variable when the program was run.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you so much.  If you care to write this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a `Pro*C` expert.  But I would expect this to be driven by the `ORACLE_SID` environment variable when the program is executed.